# Можно ли вывести данные из таблицы в виде столбца, когда требуется одно значение?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Например так:

```
Код: 1 
ФИО: Иванов. И.И...
Телефон: +71111111
```

Comment: `select concat('1', '+', '2', '=','3')`

Comment: @teran, нет , именно столбец , я не знаю почему тут энтеры не отобразились, вот так:
Код: 1\n
ФИО : И И Иванов
Телефон:.... все равно энтеры он не видит как будто, ну в общем вот так как то

Comment: А зачем это странное поведение нужно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну если мне нужно вывести одну запись из таблицы с большим количеством столбцов в текстовый файл, то зачем мне ее выводить в длинную строку?

Comment: А зачем эти столбцы в текстовом файле в виде столбца? ..........А большое количество столбцов может свидетельствовать о неправильно архитектуре БД

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, для удобства просмотра данных

Comment: А зачем они в файле? А почему запросом не посмотреть данные? А что не так просто в БД посмотреть? А в чём не удобство обычного CSV (который можно смотреть как excel)?  Удобство кому? А если больше двух записей, то в строку? ......Мне кажется вы запариваетесь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вывод в файл мне нужен просто чтобы был , больше 2ух записей мне не нужно. По заданию система должна выводить что то, поэтому я хочу это сделать

Comment: ну export csv чем плох?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я и так могу таблицу вывести в excel, но зачем мне это надо , если каждая запись в таблице представляет собой подобие документа , столбцы которой являются его реквизитами. И что бы это вывести в файл мне не нужно табличное отображение

Comment: `select 1 as x union select 2 union select 3`